# cmd move - move a couple of files

Tags: windows, command-line

Ok so I have created test folders and files to work with the cmd commands:

```
C:.
|-------test
|       \---testa
|           \---testb
|                   test1.txt
|                   test2.txt
|
|-------test2
```

My problem is that i can't get the following command to work:

```
C:\test\testa\testb>move test1.txt,test2.txt ..\..\..\test2
```

It would output `The syntax of the command is incorrect`. In `move /?`, the syntax is:

```
MOVE [/Y | /-Y] [drive:][path]filename1[,...] destination
```

I believe my syntax is correct(?). Google couldn't help me out. I know some "alternatives" to this command. What I want to know is what i did wrong that my syntax is not correct.

Comment: What destination folder is the string "..\..\..\test2**" supposed to represent?

Comment: since i am currently at the testb sub-folder, i want to go back to c:\test2 and put the files in that folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax of the `move` command in Microsoft's `cmd` as given by its `/?` option is wrong.  The correct syntax can be found in the Windows NT command references on Microsoft's WWW site, and in the Windows Command reference that may have been installed on your machine with the operating system.  Microsoft's `move` command *only supports one* source argument. For a `move` command that supports multiple source arguments, you need to use a better command interpreter.

### Further reading

- JP Software (2011). [`move`](http://jpsoft.com./help/move.htm). TCC Help and Support.
- Microsoft Corporation (2001).  [*Command-line reference A–Z*](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx). Windows XP Product Documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\test\testa\testb>move test?.txt ..\..\test2
C:\test\testa\testb\test1.txt
C:\test\testa\testb\test2.txt
        2 Datei(en) verschoben.
```

You might want to use wildcards to specify the files you want to move. Comma-seperation does not work here neither.

Comment: thanks gentlesea. but as what i have stated what i am trying to figure/find out is why my syntax was wrong. isn't it compliant to the "[path]filename1[,...]" syntax, where i can specify multiple files separated by a comma?

Comment: sorry and glad to hear it doesn't work there, too :). here is a link to an example: http://www.easydos.com/move.html

Comment: **You don't have DOS.** A DOS command reference will tell you erroneous things.