# Move all the files and folders with CMD (BAT File)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd.exe, copy-paste, cut

I want to move all the files and folders inside the folder "C:\Foldertest\" into the folder "C:\Foldertest\target".

And whenever I run this command, it does this for all files and folders except for the "C:\Foldertest\target" folder.

[image]

Comment: *to be cut*? What does that mean?

Comment: Copy all the files inside the "C: \ Foldertest" folder to the "C: \ Foldertest \ target" folder, and delete it from the "C: \ Foldertest" folder.

Comment: What's the problem? Select all the files except the target folder, then cut and paste into the target folder. Why use `cmd`?

Comment: I want to happen with file "file.bat" every 3600 seconds. I need this command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [cmd move - move a couple of files](https://superuser.com/questions/371302/cmd-move-move-a-couple-of-files)

Comment: you can use the `mv` command to movie files and folders.

Answer (score 3):

RoboCopy would be the preferred method:

```powershell
Robocopy C:\FolderTest\ c:\FolderTest\Target /E /ZB /MOVE /MOT:60
```

- *Note the trailing backslash in the source folder*

  - *Failing to include this would copy `C:\FolderTest`, rather than it's contents*

---

- **`/E`:** Copy subdirectories, including empty ones
- **`/ZB`:** Use restartable mode; if access denied use backup mode

  - *Requires user to be added to Backup Operators group, else change to **`/Z`***
- **`/MOVE`:** Move files and dirs (delete from source after copying)
- **`/MOT`:**  Monitor source; run again in X minutes, if changed

  - *You could also utilize **`/MON:1`***

    - ***`/MON`:*** Monitor source; run again when more than X changes seen

Comment: ERROR : You do not have the Backup and Restore Files user rights.
*****  You need these to perform Backup copies (/B or /ZB).

ERROR : Robocopy ran out of memory, exiting.
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #%d : "%s"

ERROR : Invalid Job File, Line #%d :"%s"

Comment: You can either add the user to the Backup Operators group, or change `/ZB` to `/Z`.  

_I've updated my answer with the aforementioned._